# somar numero e excluir \n no python

Tags: python

tenho o arquivo txt:

```
NOME,n1,n2
JOAO,8,5
MARIA,5,6
PEDRO,0,9
```

Quero somar os numeros, fiz da seguinte forma:

```
arq=open('pergunta.txt','r')
conteudo=arq.readlines()
arq.close()

for i in conteudo:
    a=i.split(',')
    b=a[1].replace('n1','')
    c=a[2].replace('n2','')
    print(int(b+c), end='')
```

No print quando nao uso o int sai assim:

```
85
56
09
```

Quando uso o int no print aparece o seguinte erro:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\n'
```

Comment: faz int(b)+int(c) que deve funcionar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro problema é que a primeira linha do seu arquivo não possui dados, mas um cabeçalho. Você até tenta tratar isso substituindo por uma *string* vazia, mas logo depois você tenta converter o valor para inteiro. Que valor inteiro deveria ser a *string* `'\n'`? Por isso dá o erro.

Você pode ignorar a primeira linha fazendo:

```
for i in conteudo[1:]:
    ...
```

Segundo problema é que quando você lê de um arquivo você sempre terá uma *string*. Ou seja, `b` e `c` serão *strings* e quando você faz `b+c` você concatenará ambas e não somar os valores inteiros. Para somar, você precisa converter para inteiro antes:

```
print( int(b) + int(c) )
```

Ficando algo assim:

```
arq=open('pergunta.txt','r')
conteudo=arq.readlines()
arq.close()

for i in conteudo[1:]:
    a=i.split(',')
    b=a[1]
    c=a[2]
    print(int(b) + int(c))
```

Mas temos como melhorar esse código...

```
import csv

with open('pergunta.txt') as stream:
    reader = csv.DictReader(stream)
    for row in reader:
        print(int(row['n1']) + int(row['n2']))
```

1. O arquivo é aberto dentro de um gerenciador de contexto, então você não precisa se preocupar em fechar o arquivo - e o arquivo é percorrido por um gerador, o que evita ter que salvar o conteúdo inteiro do arquivo em memória como acontece com o `readlines()`;
2. O arquivo é lido com auxílio do pacote `csv`, com a classe `DictReader`, que converte cada linha do arquivo em um dicionário utilizando a primeira linha como nome das colunas;
3. A soma dos valores é feita da mesma forma, mas agora acessando os valores `n1` e `n2` do dicionário;

Comment: @MatheusAndrade Tem certeza? Ele deveria exibir um abaixo do outro, pois o `print` adiciona a quebra de linha por padrão, exceto quando definido o parâmetro `end`.

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: sim mano foi por causa do end='' depois que perguntei que vi kk mas vlw